# How to use IF SQL in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Don't know how to write this code in Laravel/Eloquent.

Tried to use when(), but doesn't work for me.

```
$sql_string = "SELECT * 
        FROM 
            (
            SELECT name, priority, zone, hours, price, 
            IF (@day_hours >= ?, @day_hours := 0, @day_hours) AS hours_if, 
            IF (@day_hours = 0, @days := @days + 1, @days) AS days_if, 
            @days AS day, 
            @day_hours := @day_hours + hours AS day_hours, 
            @budget := @budget - price AS budget 
            FROM $table_name, (select @day_hours := 0, @days := 0, @budget := ?) AS INIT
            ORDER BY priority, zone 
            ) AS DATA 
        WHERE budget > 0 AND day <= ?";
```

I expect to get ready for use Eloquent code :D

Comment: Let's see your Eloquent code

Comment: I cant write this like Eloquent code. I need help to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DB::Raw](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) for these conditions:

```php
->select(DB::raw('IF (@day_hours >= ?, @day_hours := 0, @day_hours) AS hours_if'))
```